# Can I add ADMX files via symbolic links?

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link, group-policy, templates

Is it possible to add Group Policy templates (ADMX files) on a local Windows 7 machine by creating a symbolic link (soft link) in the `C:\Windows\PolicyDefinitions` folder that points to an ADMX file elsewhere?

I can make a soft link, which points to a remote folder, but GP Manager won't import it.

I'm aware that traditionally, ADMX-files are centralized by placing them into the Sysvol folder on a DC, but I don't want to do that for various reasons.